# JavaScript Event Listener for Text typed in Text Field/Area

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to use JavaScript to listen for text typed in a specific text-field, and then grab that text and save it to a string. Well, the latter (e.g., saving to string) will of course be possible if the former can be done.

I found a Java Applet that does this (http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/post1.0/ui/textlistener.html), but I was wondering if the same could be done with JS.

I'm just looking for some resources/docs.

If anyone can help, I'd much appreciate it!

Comment: 1 problem here : you won't be able to catch if the user keep  touch down. So if he enters "aaaaaaaaaaaaa" you'll catch it only when he'll release the "a" key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple with jQuery

```
$('input[name=your-input]').change( function () {

    alert(this.value); //or alert( $(this).val() );

    });
```

Comment: Thank you! I will need to listen for words as they're typed inside a  word doc in google docs, so I'm guessing I listen for changes in the class selector that golds the changing text, correct?

Comment: Correct. You can use $('.your-class') to select the class

Comment: Note that this will not fire until the input element loses focus, so for good measure I'd add a keyuplistener as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend trying JQuery which will allow you to bind to the keydown event of any element you select: http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

However, you might want to only update the string after the user has finished typing, so you might want to consider updating it whenever the textfield loses focus - which you can do by binding to the `blur` event in the same way.

EDIT: Yes - realise I was being a bit stupid here. `change` is the event you should bind to for this.

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla javascript you add an event listener:

```
document.getElementById('your-input').addEventListener('input', ()=>{
 
  console.log(this.value);

})
```